# How to switch between Python paths?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I recently downloaded anaconda, which changed my default python path to

```
 $ which python
 /anaconda3/bin/python
```

However, I'd like to switch between that and the default,

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Whats the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: Try to use virtualenvs. https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 3):

If you installed the latest version (2018.12) and let it modify your .bashrc file automatically, then you just need to deactivate conda to use the system python. Then use conda activate  to switch back into a conda environment.

```
[builder@3abd754f9aeb ~]$ which python
~/anaconda2/bin/python
[builder@3abd754f9aeb ~]$ conda deactivate
[builder@3abd754f9aeb ~]$ which python
/usr/bin/python
[builder@3abd754f9aeb ~]$ conda activate
(base) [builder@3abd754f9aeb ~]$ which python
~/anaconda2/bin/python
(base) [builder@3abd754f9aeb ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.bash_login`.

From the header of my `~/.profile`:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.
```

If it's not there, it will be in `~/.bashrc`.

If you just want to do it temporarily, you'll have to modify your `PATH`. You can see your current path with

```
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation step 7 says to edit your dotfiles for configuring the path:

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/

So edit your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` to make the change for the python path.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a little alias script that I posted in my .bashrc (hidden in your home directory). It allows you to easily switch between your systems python (somewhere in /usr) and a different local python. I used an alias instead of a custom command so it can affect the local terminals PATH easily.

I plan to use it so I don't contaminate my systems python during development.

```
alias quar='if [ "${PATH#/home/luke/bin/quarantine:}" == $PATH ]; then PATH="/home/luke/bin/quarantine:$PATH"; else echo "already quarantined"; fi'

alias unquar='if [ "${PATH#/home/luke/bin/quarantine:}" != $PATH ]; then PATH=${PATH#/home/luke/bin/quarantine:}; else echo "already unquarantined"; fi'
```

note that the folder I am pointing to myself is '/home/luke/bin/quarantine'. The point of quar / unquar is to switch that folder in and out of the front of your PATH.

Answer (score -1):

If you create virtual environments for both versions of python then its very easy to use whichever version of python you want to use. Anaconda makes it very easy to do this. There are instructions on the internet, [here for example](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/), which can help you get the environments up and running.